# pointing different subdomains to different file in htaccesswhile using wildcard subdomain function

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need help to point main domain to index.php and subdomains to its own file in htaccess while using wildcard subdomain function

for example:

test.com to index.php

ru.test.com to ru.php

de.test.com to de.php

my current htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/m/$ https://www.test.com/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobile/$ https://www.test.com/
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) index.php?query=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^search\.html$  search.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why not just use separate vhosts for each domain?

Comment: @AlexHowansky currently its shared host so have limited access, i have 10 to 15 selected subdomains like this. Thinking about using wildcard rewrite rule but then all will point to single file and the number of queries on single file will increase.

Comment: _"currently its shared host"_ Well there's your problem. Full root VPS are dirt cheap nowadays, no need to fight w/ shared hosting anymore.

Comment: What is your actual question here? You already implemented three rewrite rules. Now you need a fourth one. Which looks pretty straight forward. So why don't you simply implement that rule?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/m/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/mobile/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ $1.php?query=$2 [END]

RewriteRule ^search\.html$  search.php [NC,END]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ index.php?query=$1 [NC]
```

Note: I also fixed some other minor issues ...

An alternative to the general rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ $1.php?query=$2 [END]
```

would be a rule that specifically names the valid short codes:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|es|fr|ge|ru)/(.*)$ $1.php?query=$2 [END]
```